Mathematical intution for spin quantum number
When solving for the Schrödinger equation, we immediately get what the quantum numbers $n$, $l$ and $m$ mean, and why exactly they must have the values they are given: $n \in \mathbb{N} > 0$, $l \in \{0, 1 \dots n-1\}$, $m \in \{\pm l\}$.
Mathematically, $n$ is the order of the polynomial expansion part of the solution to the radial equation, which happens to be Laplace's equation, and its value must be finite otherwise the solution would diverge. On the other hand, $l$ and $m$ are arbitrary separation constants in the PDE, and considering that we have $3$ independent variables in that equation, we need $2$ such constants. Even though introduced as arbitrary complex numbers, their values must be the ones above, otherwise the solution wouldn't be regular at the poles.
Now I'm trying to build a similar mathematical intuition for the $s$ quantum number. To do so, I started from a set of spinor equations shown below:
\begin{equation}
 \text{eqL: } A(r) r I_2 \psi + r \sigma_1 \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r} + \sigma_2 \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \theta} + \frac{1}{\sin{\theta}}\sigma_3 \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \phi} = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \text{eqR: } A(r) r I_2 \psi - r \sigma_1 \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r} - \sigma_2 \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \theta} - \frac{1}{\sin{\theta}}\sigma_3 \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \phi} = 0
\end{equation}
These equations represent the left-handed and right-handed equations for a Weyl particle under a potential $V(r)$ with
\begin{equation}
    A(r) = E - V(r)
\end{equation}
I decided to start from Weyl equations for simplicity, even though I don't know how much of a gain this is since I'm using four equations just like Dirac's would be.
When the $\sigma_i$ are explicitly introduced, this set becomes:
\begin{equation}
  \text{eqL1:} \quad r A f_{1} + r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} f_{2} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f_{2} + \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial p} f_{1}}{\sin{\left(t \right)}} = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
  \text{eqL2:} \quad r A f_{2} + r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} f_{1} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f_{1} - \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial p} f_{2}}{\sin{\left(t \right)}} = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation} 
\text{eqR1:} \quad r A f_{1} - r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} f_{2} + i \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f_{2} - \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial p} f_{1}}{\sin{\left(t \right)}} = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\text{eqR1:} \quad A f_{2} - r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} f_{1} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f_{1} + \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial p} f_{2}}{\sin{\left(t \right)}} = 0
\end{equation}
Summing and subtracting these equations, we get:
\begin{equation}
    ( \text{eqL} + \text{eqR})/2 = ( \text{eqL} - \text{eqR})/2 = 0
\end{equation}
So,
\begin{equation}
  r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} f_{2} - r A f_{1} = i \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f_{2} - \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial p} f_{1}}{\sin{\left(t \right)}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  r \frac{\partial}{\partial r} f_{1} + r A f_{2} = - i \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f_{1} + \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial p} f_{2}}{\sin{\left(t \right)}}
\end{equation}
I guess that at this point, somehow we will identify the right-hand side of these equations with spinor spherical harmonics and separate the equations for $f_1$ and $f_2$ using an arbitrary separation constant $s$, and in the end acknowledge that $s \in \{\pm \frac{1}{2}\}$ due to some conditions. However, I don't know how to proceed and

justify such a separation;
what are the conditions that lead to the specific values for $s$.

Does this reasoning proceed? Is spin quantum number $s$ a separation constant? And if so, how to identify the equation whose solutions are spinor spherical harmonics, and what are the conditions that lead to $s \in \{\pm \frac{1}{2}\}$?
